# DS1307 RTC not working with CC3000 WiFi shield (I2C bus hangs)

Tags: i2c, wifi, rtc

I am trying to use a DS1307 (from Sparkfun, [BOB-12708](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12708)) with an Arduino Leonardo. I have connected the SDA, SCL, GND, and 5V pins from the RTC to the Arduino. However, with a CC3000 WiFi shield on the Arduino, the I2C bus hangs. Specifically, `Wire.endtransmission()` hangs, called by `rtc.isrunning()`. I have confirmed that it works properly on the same Arduino without the WiFi shield. I am using the ds1307 RTClib example for testing it.

Comment: Which CC3000 breakout exactly? This may be related to the fact that the CC3000 employs interrupts; they could be interrupting the I2C transaction. Post the code that combines the CC3000 and the RTC.

Comment: It's the CC3000 shield.

Comment: Adafruit and Sparkfun both produce CC3000 shields, among others. Which one is yours?

Comment: I have the one from Adafruit: https://www.adafruit.com/product/1491

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the CC3000 interrupts are affecting the Wire library's behaviour since the latter is interrupt-driven itself. 
Try disabling the CC3000 IRQ before calling `rtc.isrunning()` or any other RTC functions. First `#include "ccspi.h"` in your sketch. Then place `WlanInterruptDisable()` before any `RTClib` function call, and then `WlanInterruptEnable()` after the RTC function returns.

Even if this works, it may affect the functionality of the CC3000, since it increases the chances of missed interrupts. You can search for DS1307 libraries that employ SoftwareI2C instead such as [this one](https://github.com/kamermans/SoftDS1307RTC). They should be better able to recover from the CC3000 interrupts.

Comment: As I've said in my OP, it doesn't work even with just the RTC example. Would CC3000 interrupts be messing with things even if the library isn't included?

Comment: No, it wouldnt. Somehow, I thought you meant that you used the examples together with the CC3000 code. How are you powering the CC3000? Directly from the Arduino?

Comment: The CC3000 is a shield, so yes it is directly powered from the Arduino which is powered by USB for testing.

Comment: Powering the CC3000 via USB can cause unreliable behaviour since USB can only supply so much current. Try connecting the shield to the Arduino with jumper cables and powering the shield separately with a 1A source, while connecting all the GNDs together.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a USB to wall adapter can supply a lot more current, correct? Might that work? I could probably also rig something up if it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, a USB-wall adapter should be alright, but read the specs on the body, to be sure.

Comment: That seems to be part of the solution, but something is still not working and I can't debug it since it has to be connected to the wall. I've been using the builtin LED to debug it, but there's only so much I can do. I tried netcat + a simple CC3000 socket, but it hung on establishing the CC3000 socket on my computer power (expected) and I can't debug it well without Serial. I might look into using two arduinos to assist with debugging later (one with a CC3000 connected to the wall, the other connected to my computer, both connected to each other via digital pins).

Comment: It doesnt have to be connected to the wall. You could use 4 1.5V batteries in series to power the CC3000.

Comment: For some reason I thought you couldn't have both VIN and USB connected, looking at the documentation it would appear I am wrong. That will be useful. Thank you!

Comment: @PlasmaPower Sure. But I wasnt talking about powering the Arduino, only the CC3000. I used batteries for a while, through lots of tests, before they got drained.

Comment: I'm using the CC3000 shield, not the breakout however. Powering them separately would be either impossible or at the least very tricky.

Comment: Not necessarily. The actual connections from shield to Uno are only 7. Look here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-cc3000-wifi/connections. You can use male-female jumpers, if you have them. Also how are you connecting the RTC to the Arduino, with the shield on top?

Comment: I'm stuck with a Leonardo for now, which also requires the ICSP pins, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference. As for connecting the RTC, the RTC is a breakout of course, and it's connected through SCL and SDA (but currently I'm using SoftI2C).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39413/discussion-between-tisteandii-and-plasmapower).